# Execute PHP script without Redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have below Rewrite rule in `.htaccess`:

```
# /m/yyy rule
RewriteRule ^m/([\w-]+)/?$ accounts/$1/index.php [L,NC]
# /m/yyy/abc rule
RewriteRule ^m/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)$ accounts/$1/$2.php [L,NC]
# /m/yyy/abc/ rule
RewriteRule ^m/([\w-]+)/([\w-]+)/$ accounts/$1/$2/index.php [L,NC]
```

I want to execute the PHP script view.php if the URL is `https://example.com/m/mya/view.php`, I expect `accounts/mya/view.php` to be executed.

Please advise how I can do.

Comment: Could you please confirm which url you are hitting and which url you want it to rewrite or redirect(if any in browser)? Thank you.

Comment: "Execute PHP script without Rewrite" - I've "corrected" your title, as I assume you meant "Redirect", not "Rewrite". The only way you can do what you are asking is with an internal _rewrite_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your existing rules are being used for other purposes, since none of them will match the stated URL.

To internally rewrite the request `/m/mya/view.php` to `/accounts/mya/view.php` (as stated) then you would add the following before (or after) your existing rules:

```
RewriteRule ^m/(mya/view\.php)$ accounts/$1 [L]
```

To make this more generic and rewrite the request `/m/<file>` to `/accounts/<file>`, but only if `/accounts/<file>` exists then you can do something like the following instead before (or after) your existing rules:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/accounts/$1 -f
RewriteRule ^m/([\w/-]+\.\w{2,5})$ accounts/$1 [L]
```

**UPDATE:** The regex part `\.\w{2,5}` matches, what looks-like, a file extension. ie. a dot followed by between 2 and 5 *word* characters. If you are only matching `.php` files then you can change this to `\.php` to hardcode the `.php` extension. Use a regex testing tool such as [`regex101.com`](https://regex101.com/r/1zJQiY/1) to test this and get a detailed explanation of the regex (this is not unique to Apache - Apache uses the same regex engine as PHP and other languages, ie. PCRE).

The preceding `RewriteCond` (*condition*) directive then checks that this file exists at the intended destination before actually rewriting the request. Without this, the request is rewritten unconditionally, regardless of whether the target file exists or not. eg. `/m/abc/xyz/does-not-exist.php` would be internally rewritten to `/accounts/abc/xyz/does-not-exist.php` which then triggers a 404 *later* (potentially exposing the `accounts` subdirectory - depending on how you are handling your 404s).

The order of these rules in relation to your existing rules as posted does not matter since the regex (`RewriteRule` *patterns*) do not conflict when making a request for a file (that contains a dot before the file extension).

Comment: Thanks @MrWhite, I tested but know I idea to the RewriteCond and the w{2,5} mean, here is my test https://htaccess.madewithlove.com?share=af545ff4-0a53-45db-9322-afa4253f3c98

Comment: @Kelvin I've updated my answer with more details on those points. You cannot use the MWL `.htaccess` tester to test this properly since it has no knowledge of the filesystem (and does not support the `-f` file check).